# How to calculate total of cells while there are blank ones?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

*Hello SO People;*

My problem when calculating the total of the DataGridView.cells While null cells are present, it returns "Conversion from 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid." how to avoid the problem assuming are null cells.

```
For Each colonne As DataGridViewRow In TDgrdView.Rows
    If TDgrdView.RowCount > 1 Then
         Dim monTotal As Decimal = 0
         For ind As Integer = 0 To TDgrdView.RowCount - 1
               monTotal += Convert.ToDouble(TDgrdView.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value)
         Next
         txtTotal.Text = monTotal
    End If
Next
```

> **Note:** The code works without null cells.
>   *Thank you! in advance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DBNull` to validate whether the column is null or not. If it is, then do not include it in the computation of `monTotal`.

So little modifications to your code should be something like:

```
If Not IsDBNull(TDgrdView.Rows(ind).Cells(1).Value) Then
    monTotal += Convert.ToDouble(TDgrdView.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value)
End If
```

Also I supposed that `ind` is a typo for your index, and refactoring the above code should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the nullvalue of the defaultcellstyle to 0 should fix the problem.